# Support Reddit Accounts

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, reddit

Reddit seems to support [OAuth2](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2). Either way, subreddits like [/r/ElementaryOS](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/3bxygw/meta_stackexchange_vs_this_subreddit/) have expressed interest in using Stack Exchange for their bug reports and Q&A-style posts.

SE offers a better Q&A experience than Reddit. But without having Reddit accounts supported on SE, there's a barrier to entry that novice users might find intolerable.

Comment: @rene: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/ is where they will go. I am a moderator at a gaming subreddit and would love for Q&A and bug reports to go onto the superior Gaming Stack Exchange site.

Comment: How is not having Reddit support intolerable for users? I find that the support of signing-up/logging-in by OAuth, Google, Facebook or even just by Email removes the '*barrier*' you speak of. Can you expand on your point?

Comment: How many people are smart enough to file bug reports (about reddit or any other software), but not smart enough to sign in to SE using one of the existing methods? (Not that I'm opposed to supporting Reddit logins, but the rationale seems exaggerated to me).

Comment: Not just bug reports. The same tech support question can be asked dozens of times on Reddit, because it doesn't have the proactive search function that Stack Exchange has.

Comment: All else aside, our Q&A sites aren't the right place to report bugs for any software (except our own, on our meta sites). For more info, see [Can I support my product on this site?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support).